# Error: "Your Application class does not have a bootstrap() method. Please add one."

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line, cakephp-4.x

I recently started building an application, locally, using CakePHP 4.X. I installed Composer and successfully installed the CakePHP Authentication and Authorization plugins using it. Now, I'm trying to move on to some community-developed plugins such as

- https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui
- https://github.com/gutocf/page-title
- https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-feedback

I'm able to install all of the plugins okay but the issue arises when I try to load the plugins.  Per the instructions on each of the plugin Git pages, I try to load the plugin from my CLI using the line

```
bin\cake plugin load BootstrapUI
```

(I'm on Windows hence the backslash)

I am returned the following message in all cases:

```
Your Application class does not have a bootstrap() method. Please add one.
```

My **src/Application.php** file looks like this

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
public function bootstrap() : void
{
    // Call the parent to `require_once` config/bootstrap.php
    parent::bootstrap();

    if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        $this->bootstrapCli();
    } else {
        FactoryLocator::add(
            'Table',
            (new TableLocator())->allowFallbackClass(false)
        );
    }

    /*
     * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
     * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
     */
    if (Configure::read('debug')) {
        $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
    }

    // Load more plugins here
    $this->addPlugin('Authorization');
    $this->addPlugin('Authentication');
    $this->addPlugin('BootstrapUI');
    
}
```

Comment: That's not valid PHP, please make sure that you show the exact code that you're using, including the _exact_ indentations (they are relevant in this specific case)! Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or run `bin/cake version`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Application class is missing an `{` after `class Application extends BaseApplication` but I guess it was pasted/edited incorrectly here.

Your command seems to work because I see the plugin `$this->addPlugin('BootstrapUI')` already added in the file.

Make sure to be on the correct path (in the root of your app) when you execute the CLI command:

```
bin\cake plugin load BootstrapUI
```

You can manually add the plugins in the bootstrap() method without CLI.